# Obj-C, Reference-counted object is used after it is released?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I`m getting the following warning.

**Reference-counted object is used after it is released**

ARC is enabled for this file.

I have not converted my app to use ARC and don`t have an proper understanding of it at this time. However, at a glance I am puzzled why this code should have a problem (its from a library), I mean I know autorelease should not be used here?

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id uuid = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueID"];
    if (uuid)
        uniqueID = (NSString *)uuid;
    else {
        CFStringRef cfUuid = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, CFUUIDCreate(NULL));
        uniqueID = (__bridge NSString *)cfUuid;
        CFRelease(cfUuid);
        [defaults setObject:uniqueID forKey:@"uniqueID"]; // warning here
    }
```

EDIT 
@JohnCalsbeek, @epatel, @Chuck
Thanks, I've just tried that and I get a new warning on `CFStringRef cfUuid` line, saying potential leak.

Heres the full file https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKSKProduct.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, srry for the miss understanding haha

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id uuid = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueID"];

if (uuid)
    uniqueID = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)uuid];
else {
    CFUUIDRef temp = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef cfUuid = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, temp);
    uniqueID = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString*) cfUuid];
    CFRelease(cfUuid);
    CFRelease(temp);

    [defaults setObject:uniqueID forKey:@"uniqueID"]; // warning here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me errors https://img.skitch.com/20120326-b9692kiegw7xhehipj8rgw3y53.jpg

Comment: @Jules Actually i just realized that this is a CCFUID identifier, let me edit my answer.

Comment: @Jules forgot to tell you, with the clang static analyzer this becomes very easy to understand. (you can turn it in your project debug options)

Comment: Thanks @LuisOscar that's fixed it, will I be OK turning on the clang static analyzer if only a few files are using ARC ?

Comment: To be honest i have no idea, since i started using it along with arc. give it a try and if you get too many weird errors you could just turn it off haha. good luck

Answer (score 2):

A `__bridge` cast is not a transfer of ownership. `uniqueID` does not become an owning reference, and so becomes invalid at the line with the warning. You can either use `__bridge_transfer` (which transfers ownership to the Objective-C reference) and remove your `CFRelease` call, or change the call to `CFRelease` to be after the call to `-setObject:forKey:`.

Comment: Did you try the `__bridge_transfer` version?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can be this line that doesn't do what you expect

```
uniqueID = (__bridge NSString *)cfUuid;
```

It is a simple cast and the next line will actually release both `cfUuid` and `uniqueID` (which actually is the same object).

So I'd change the order of the following lines to

```
[defaults setObject:uniqueID forKey:@"uniqueID"]; // warning here
CFRelease(cfUuid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a string with `CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, CFUUIDCreate(NULL)`. Then you assign `uniqueID` to also refer to that string. Then you release the string with `CFRelease(cfUuid)`. Then you use the string (as `uniqueID`) on the next line. That's invalid, because you just released it.